# MBed RTOS doesnt respond to serial

Tags: rtos, mbed

I am writing an application where I wait for commands to come in from serial and convert led colours according to the data. I have each element working in its own right:

1. Recieving and sending commands over serial connection
2. Changing the LED colours
3. Change led colours directly when command recieved (no RTOS).

I need the LED loop to keep working until new data has arrived But when I use the thread from the RTOS library the led's dont change. This makes me think its a problem with my code and RTOS, the problem is I cant see whats causing it.

From debugging (printing strings over serial to the pc) I see the thread is running and looping around, it uses the values set when the variables are created. The main thread seems to have stalled as theres no output to the console (or reading of the serial in).

If I dont start the thread the serial comms works again confirming that the problem lies with my code and the RTOS library.

From reading other forums and posts I have read that it could be a problem with serial and RTOS and followed the suggestion of removing all printf functions and changing to RawSerial but this didnt do anything.

I would really appreciate any help to get the code working as intended

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "rtos.h"
#include "xbee.h"
#include "CMDLIB.h"
#include "WS2812.h"
#include "PixelArray.h"

#define LED_COUNT1 134
#define OUT_WHEEL 28

char startChar = '$';
char endChar = ';';

Serial pc( USBTX, USBRX ); // tx, rx

CMDLIB cmd;
xbee xbee( p28, p27, p29, 38400 );
PixelArray px1( LED_COUNT1 );
WS2812 set1( p5, 144, 3, 11, 10, 11 );
Thread ledthread;

int ledFunction;
int colour1[3], colour2[3], speed, intensity;

//LED Functions
void offLED()
{
    for( int i = 1; i < LED_COUNT1; i++ )
    {
        px1.Set( i, 0x000000 );
    }
    set1.write( px1.getBuf() );
}

void solidPulse( int colour, int speed, int intensity )
{
    px1.SetAll( colour );
    //pc.printf("2\r\n");
    set1.write( px1.getBuf() );
    //pc.printf("3\r\n");
    for( int a = 255; a > intensity; a-- )
    {
        px1.SetAllI( a );
        set1.write( px1.getBuf() );
        wait_ms( speed );
        //pc.printf("%d,",a);
    }
    //pc.printf("\r\n4\r\n");
    for( int a = intensity; a < 255; a++ )
    {
        px1.SetAllI( a );
        set1.write( px1.getBuf() );
        wait_ms( speed );
        //pc.printf("%d,",a);
    }
    //pc.printf("\r\n5\r\n");

}

void ledThread()
{
    while( 1 )
    {
        switch( ledFunction )
        {
            case 0: //Off
                //offLED();
            break;
            case 1: //Solid
                //pc.printf("1\r\n");
            solidPulse( cmd.RGB2HEX( colour1[0], colour1[1], colour1[2] ), speed, intensity );
            break;
            case 2: //Solid Pulse
            solidPulse( cmd.RGB2HEX( colour1[0], colour1[1], colour1[2] ), speed, intensity );
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
        //pc.printf("%d;\r\n", ledFunction);
        wait_ms( 200 );
    }
}

void setup()
{
    set1.useII( WS2812::PER_PIXEL ); // use per-pixel intensity scaling
    xbee.setup( startChar, endChar );
    pc.baud( 38400 );
    muxcon = 0;
    ledFunction = 0;
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    {
        colour1[j] = 1;
        colour2[j] = 1;
    }
    speed = 100;
    intensity = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < LED_COUNT1; i++ )
    {
        px1.Set( i, 0xffffff );
    }
    set1.write( px1.getBuf() );
}

char * convertChar( string data )
{
    char * chars = "";
    for( int k = 0; k < data.size(); k++ )
    {
        chars += data[k];
    }
    return chars;
}

int main()
{
    setup();
    ledthread.start( ledThread );
    string recData;
    while( true )
    {
        if( xbee.readable() )
        {
            recData = xbee.readData();
            //pc.printf("Recieved Data: %s\r\n",recData);
            string cmdString = cmd.getCommand( recData );
            if( cmdString == "[TEL]" )
            {
                gatherTelemetry();
                string telResult = cmd.formatTelemetry( sData1, sData2, sData3, sData4, sData5, sData6 );
                xbee.sendData( telResult );
            }
            if( cmdString == "[LED]" )
            {
                //pc.printf("[RES],LED;\r\n");

                string res[10];
                int count = 0;
                char c;
                for( int j = 0; j < recData.size(); j++ )
                {
                    c = recData[j];
                    if( c == ',' || c == ';' )
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res[count] += c;
                    }
                }
                ledFunction = atoi( res[1].c_str() );
                colour1[0] = atoi( res[2].c_str() );
                colour1[1] = atoi( res[3].c_str() );
                colour1[2] = atoi( res[4].c_str() );
                colour2[0] = atoi( res[5].c_str() );
                colour2[1] = atoi( res[6].c_str() );
                colour2[2] = atoi( res[7].c_str() );
                speed = atoi( res[8].c_str() );
                intensity = atoi( res[9].c_str() );
                //pc.printf("Raw Values: %s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s\r\n",res[0],res[1],res[2],res[3],res[4],res[5],res[6],res[7],res[8],res[9]);
                //pc.printf("Converted: %d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\r\n",ledFunction,colour1[0],colour1[1],colour1[2],colour2[0],colour2[1],colour2[2],speed,intensity);


                xbee.sendData( "[RES],OK" );

                //solidPulse(cmd.RGB2HEX(colour1[0], colour1[1], colour1[2]), speed, intensity);
            }
            if( cmdString == "[CMD]" )
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wait_ms` function does not put the running thread into the waiting state and does not allow another thread to run.  So your `ledThread` never gives up control. 
 Instead ledThread should call `Thread::wait`, which does put the current thread into the waiting state and allows the next ready thread to run.

You may also need to change the `main` while loop so that it gives up control and allows ledThread to run again.

Comment: How would you make the main thread give up control, thread wait?

Comment: @NoLiver92 : That is one way, but in an RTOS the highest priority task that can run will run.  A task can run when it is not _blocked_. `Thread::wait` is the simplest method of blocking, but does not allow true real-time response to incoming commands; a better approach would be to have a blocking wait on `xbee`; which would require the `xbee` class to be mBed RTOS aware.  That is you'd need a blocking wait to replace `xbee::readable()`.  It may not matter if you periodically poll `xbee::readable`, but in other cases where immediate real-time response is required polling may be inadequate.